# Authentication failures in cassandra when 1 of 16 nodes is down

Tags: authentication, cassandra

I have a Cassandra cluster running :

*Cassandra 2.0.11.83 | DSE 4.6.0 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0*

The cluster has 18 nodes, split among 3 datacenters, 6 in each. My system_auth keyspace has the following replication defined:

*replication = {
  'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy',
  'DC1': '4',
  'DC2': '4',
  'DC3': '4'}*

and my authenticator/authorizer are set to:

*authenticator: org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator*

*authorizer: org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraAuthorizer*

This morning I brought down one of the nodes in DC1 for maintenance. Within a few seconds/minute client applications started logging exceptions like this:

*"User my_application_user has no MODIFY permission on  or any of its parents"*

Running 'LIST ALL PERMISSIONS of my_application_user' on one of the other nodes shows that user to have SELECT and MODIFY on the keyspace xxxxx, so I am rather confused. Do I have a setup issue? Is this a bug of some sort?

Comment: You'll want to make sure you also have increased the replication factor for dse_security, then run nodetool repair on both keyspaces (ref: [Configuring system_auth and dse_security keyspace replication | DataStax Enterprise 4.7 Documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/sec/secConfSysAuthKeyspRepl.html)).

Comment: Thank you BrianC. I checked and I don't seem to have that keyspace - the only ones I have (other than user-created ones) are: "system  dse_system  system_auth  system_traces". This cluster used to be on DSE 4.0.1 at one point and was upgraded to 4.6.0, so maybe that's why? dse_system ks is set with rep of EverywhereStrategy, and system ks is with LocalStrategy. All others are with NetworkTopologyStrategy. What am I missing? Thank you again for responding!

Comment: the two things to check are that all those keyspaces have enough replication as needed in each DC. The one you show for system_auth is fine, as are any that use EverywhereStrategy (where it happens automatically). Then the second thing is to do a nodetool repair on all nodes for those keyspaces after changing the RF. I don't know if this is your problem or not, but that's where I would start. Have you also tried the "list all permissions" check on each node to make sure they all agree?

Comment: Hi BrianC, thanks for sticking with me. :) The cluster has an OpsCenter repair service running, and it has completed at least 3-4 repair passes since the last time there was a change to a user name/pass, and even more since the RF was changed last. I also tested logging in as that user on every node (via 'cqlsh LocalNodeIP -u my_application_user -p user_pass -f commands_file_containing_list_all_permissions_for_user' and it logs on fine to all nodes and they agree on the permissions. I will try running a manual repair on the system_auth KS and see how that goes. Any other KSs?

Comment: BTW, my end goal is to decommission half of the nodes, and the one that is giving me the issue (causing login failures when I brought it down for maintenance) is one of the ones slated for decom, so I need to figure out what the deal is, before nuking it and shooting myself in the foot. :(

Comment: So this is resolved, here's the sequence of events: add 18 more nodes, run cleanup on original nodes (this was part of the original plan), run a scrub on 1 table, since it was throwing exceptions on cleanup, run a repair on the system_auth KS on the original troubled node, wait for repair service to complete a full pass on all KSs, decom original 18 nodes. Honestly, I don't know what fixed it. The system_auth repair makes most sense, but what doesn't make sense is that it had run many passes before, so why work now, I don't know. I hope this at least helps someone. Thanks BrianC for your help!

Comment: glad you were able to get to the bottom of it, even if the route didn't make complete sense :) you might want to write up your conclusion as an answer which you can accept, for future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-posting this as the answer, as BrianC suggested above.

So this is resolved... Here's the sequence of events that seems to have fixed it:

1. Add 18 more nodes
2. Run cleanup on original nodes (this was part of the original plan)
3. Run a scrub on 1 table, since it was throwing exceptions on cleanup
4. Run a repair on the system_auth KS on the original troubled node
5. Wait for repair service to complete a full pass on all keyspaces
6. Decom original 18 nodes.

Honestly, I don't know what fixed it. The system_auth repair makes most sense, but what doesn't make sense is that it had run many passes before, so why work now, I don't know. I hope this at least helps someone.